# Cycles is not using the materials created by MakeHuman

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

I am using a blender and  MakeHuman .mhx file to model some persons moved in a scene and captured by a fisheye lens camera.

I model a person with clothes on MakeHuman and I load it in blender in mode Cycles Render (because fihseye lens work only in Cycles Render). When I render I get a person without clothes and a lot of noise caused by the light (see image1). But in Blender Render I get the person with clothes (see image 2).
[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the Make Human importer sets up a Blender Internal Material based on the Material that's in the file you imported.  This is not automatic yet for Cycles rendering yet.

First you have to go to the Materials Tab and click the 'Use Nodes' button.

Now you can up the Node Editor and add an Image Texture.  Next, plug the Texture's Color output into the the Shader node's Color input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in my case ,it is an armature, so there is no material and in the texture there is no node button.

Comment: armatures never render. They aren't supposed to. I think you may be confused...

Comment: What @MarcClintDion says is makehuman exports blender internal materials which have to be recreated (manually by you) in cycles. As a second opinion I confirm (hope that makes sense in English) that.

Answer (score 0):

first enable all layers ("~" key), and find the body model (it's attached to the armature, so in the outliner window it's inside the armature). next play with materials for body and its parts (eyes, hair, eyelashes, eyebrows, genitals, etc). you're to setup all needed materials to cycle style. a little tip - use "F" button (it's next to material name) to add fake user to all of your old and new materials to prevent losing them on file save.
there are a lot of tutorials how to use textures in cycles, transparent ones as well (you'll need it for hair, eyelashes, etc). happy blending!

Comment: now there is a simpler way. just use mhx2 importer from makehuman. when importing it to scene with cycles render selected it automatically creates all the cycles materials!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comment by Mechanic.
In the latest blender release, use the mhx2 importer but you must first select the Cycles Render before importing the mhx2 file!